# Get accuracy from pandas confusion matrix stats

Tags: python, pandas, confusion-matrix

How do I get the accuracy information from a pandas confusion matrix? I'd like to just have the number. I haven't been able to find it through Google and I'm hoping to just do something like this:

```
overall_error = 1 - matrix1.accuracy
```

If I do:

```
print matrix1.print_stats()
```

one of the lines will be:

```
Accuracy: 0.8203
```

but I can't get just that number without printing a big block of text with the other information.

Comment: what is a pandas confusion matrix?

Comment: @cel hover over the tags on the question

Comment: I know pandas, but I am not aware of a special confusion matrix in pandas.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas_confusion/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Didn't know that project!

Comment: @cel it's pretty cool! Thanks for checking out the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cm.stats()['overall']['Accuracy']
```

Should do it (where cm is the matrix you have loaded). As mentioned in the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas_confusion/), cm.stats() returns an ordered dict instead of a printout.